# _main() unresolved

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I wrote program in C using visual studio 2013 , but i got this error:
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

I don't know what is it mean and how to fix it.this is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int getArr(int arr[]){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    return n;
}

void putArr(int arr[],int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void sort(int Arr[],int nArr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<nArr-1;i++)
    {
        int minIndex=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<nArr;j++)
            if(Arr[j]<Arr[minIndex])
                minIndex=j;
        int t=Arr[i];
        Arr[i]=Arr[minIndex];
        Arr[minIndex]=t;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int nArr;
    nArr=getArr(arr);
    sort(arr,nArr);
    putArr(arr,nArr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile a simple C program as windows console application. Which I believe require `main` to be named `tmain`, if I recall correctly..

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Which would be against the standard, including C90 which MSVC - IIRC - claims to be compliant.

Comment: Looks more like a broken toolchain or wrong usage. @AmirAli, please add info which compiler you are using and how you invoke it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I use the regular visual studio 2013 and its own compiler

Comment: @AmirAli so all done from within VS, no command line invocation? That should "just work" OOTB. Without analyzing the code, I can assure you it's not the code causing **this** error. You should use `int main(void)` here, but that's also not the problem ....

Comment: @FelixPalmen I don't get it,what do you mean?

Comment: @AmirAli `int main()` would take *any* number of arguments. The only valid choices for `main()` according to standard C are `int main(void)` (**no** arguments) and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (two arguments). But as I said, that's also not the root cause of your problem here ....

Comment: @AmirAli what kind of project did you create? Are your files named `.c` and not `.cpp`? There's also an option to *force* compilation in [tag:c] mode (instead of [tag:c++]), but I don't remember it right now...

Comment: @Olaf Not sure about this MSVC at all. Just created a "Win32 Console C++ Application" project (yes, c++, I know), and the template has `_tmain` named function instead of `main`. I believe `main` is buried somewhere deep in the precompiled stuff.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Cant help much with that. happily not using this crap.

Comment: VC10's win32-console app (empty, default settings) compiles fine with a single `int main() {}` added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code as written builds fine with VS 2012, VS 2013, or VS 2015 using the command-line tools (via the "Developer Command Prompt for VS xxxx" window).

Windows has three types of main for C/C++ console apps:

`main`: This is the traditional ANSI main which takes command-line parameters as `char*`

`wmain`: This is the Unicode main which takes command-line parameters as `wchar_t*`

`_tmain`: This is the `_TCHAR` version which can build as either ANSI or Unicode. This is what the default template uses and is set to build as Unicode.

If you changed your `void main()` to `void wmain()` it would build as well since the default template project settings is set to "Use Unicode Character Set" which on the command-line adds `/D_UNICODE /DUNICODE`

If you go to Project -> Properties -> General and set *Character Set* to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" for All Configurations and All Platforms, then your use of `void main()` will successfully link. This uses `/D_MBCS` for the command-line instead of  `/D_UNICODE /DUNICODE`

That said, with VS 2013's default project your code builds fine replacing the existing `_tmain` with your `main` even without changing the character set setting.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio dont want that user declare variables in case, or for instructions
use a declaration a the start of function corpus. Good Luck

```
#include<stdio.h>

int getArr(int arr[]){
int n,i;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
return n;
}

void putArr(int arr[],int n)
{
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
printf("\n");
}

void sort(int Arr[],int nArr)
{
int j, i=0;
int t;

for(i=0;i<nArr-1;i++)
{
int minIndex=i;
for( j=i+1;j<nArr;j++)
if(Arr[j]<Arr[minIndex])
minIndex=j;
t=Arr[i];
Arr[i]=Arr[minIndex];
Arr[minIndex]=t;
}
}


int main()
{
int arr[100];
int nArr;
nArr=getArr(arr);
sort(arr,nArr);
putArr(arr,nArr);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a windows application project you should select console Application when creating a new project or if you want to learn win32 programming you can use
below links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381398(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.catch22.net/

http://pravin.paratey.com/win32/
http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/windows/windows_tutorial_1.shtm